# Sql query to get previous row and compare time according to other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know my question is not clear from its title but i am stuck in complex scenario
My table output is as

```
+----+-------------+-----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Id | personCount |  StatusId |      MinStartTime       |       MinEndTime        |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | 3           | 1         | 2014-02-20 07:03:50.137 | 2014-02-20 07:38:33.400 |
| 2  | 3           | 8         | 2014-02-20 07:13:08.327 | 2014-02-20 07:21:28.697 |
| 3  | 3           | 2         | 2014-02-20 07:25:06.257 | 2014-02-20 07:47:32.507 |
| 4  | 4           | 1         | 2014-02-20 07:38:33.400 | 2014-02-20 12:03:03.550 |
| 5  | 4           | 2         | 2014-02-20 07:47:32.507 | 2014-02-20 08:02:10.707 |
| 6  | 4           | 8         | 2014-02-20 08:16:32.370 | 2014-02-20 11:11:02.900 |
| 7  | 4           | 8         | 2014-02-20 11:52:12.777 | 2014-02-20 12:03:03.550 |
| 8  | 0           | 1         | 2014-02-20 12:03:03.550 | 2014-02-21 05:22:45.287 |
| 9  | 2           | 1         | 2014-02-21 05:22:45.303 | 2014-02-25 10:47:22.590 |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Now if you look at Id =4 row ,its status is 1  and previous row id=3 status is 2.
As 3rd row is Endtime is greater than 4th row starttime

So i want to compare person count of 4th row with person count of its previous row where status id is 1 ie. id=1  and if person count is less than i want to update the Id=4 row with person count as 4-3 ie. 1

Hope i have made it simple to understand.

Now i can get previous row with self join and compare the values but then how can i compare that value with its previous row where status id is 1

Query i am using to get previous row in this case

```
select tnext.Id,tnext.personCount
from @TableDataStatus t join
     @TableDataStatus tnext
     on t.id = tnext.id - 1 and
        t.StatusId = 2 and
        tnext.StatusId = 1 and
        CONVERT(char(16),tnext.MinStartTime,120)<CONVERT(char(16),t.MinEndTime,120)
```

Which will return me Id=4 which is right now how do i compare with previous row with status id=1

Comment: I read your explanation a couple of times, but it is very confusing.  Can you explain what the operation is trying to accomplish?

Comment: And in additions to @Seano666 request, if you can post the sample output for this sample input, it would help making things clearer.

Comment: why are you converting datetime to char?

Comment: `So i want to compare person count of 4th row with person count of its previous row where status id is 1 ie. id=1 and if person count is less than i want to update the Id=4 row with person count as 4-3 ie. 1` ??

Answer (score 0):

Following Self Join query over ID's will list the current row and the previous row side by side

```
select * 
from @TableDataStatus curr
left join @TableDataStatus prev on curr.id = prev.id + 1
```

But other conditions like StatusId or conditions on datetime columns prevents finding a previous data row for each of the current data.

For example following code returns only 4th row with its previous 3rd row

```
select * 
from MyTables curr
left join MyTables prev on curr.id = prev.id + 1
where
    prev.StatusId = 2 and
    curr.StatusId = 1 and
    curr.MinStartTime < prev.MinEndTime
```

If 4th row is the only target, then you can test following UPDATE statement

```
UPDATE MyTables
SET 
    personCount = MyTables.personCount - prev.personCount
from MyTables
left join MyTables prev on MyTables.id = prev.id + 1
where
    prev.StatusId = 2 and
    MyTables.StatusId = 1 and
    MyTables.MinStartTime < prev.MinEndTime
```